# Django 3 - How to create many pages and then show them on menu?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am new in python Django and practicing it.
I have a Wordpress site and I want to migrate it to Django. I can create blogs, pages etc on Django but the problem is I have to make 20+ pages of that site if I move it to Django. And to show them like parent and children of pages.
I can create single pages in Django and show them in template.

But I want to make it from admin panel. So me and in future, my client can create new pages easily and I want them to automatically view on navigation.
I want it just like wordpress, create a page, save it and boom, it will be live on frontpage(if configured in settings).

I searched for the help or right direction but cant find anywhere.

**Please someone point me which is the best way to achieve this ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Wagtail, it does exactly what you want and can be run alongside vanilla django: https://wagtail.io/

Comment: After looking for some time to Waigtail, I found the vanilla Django easier than Wagtail. Still confused.

Comment: Still waiting for solution. :(

Comment: If you don't want to go with wagtail, you will have to implement the same thing yourself. Create models for the pages, with a foreign key to another page that would be the parent. Then render the page(s) according to your wishes. With it all being model-based, you can add new pages in the admin panel.

Comment: I finally ended up with Wagtail. Thanks.